# Efficient MySQL Database Design for Multi-User Web Apps

Tags: mysql, database

I am developing a site that will allow for users to track sales numbers for personal crafts. The way it will work is that a user will be able to submit/edit weekly sales data, and then once the data is stored, be able to view it in various forms of table or graph, track trends, etc.

My concern is that as the userbase grows, if it grows, I want a database design that will scale with it, and be manageable. I am self taught when it comes to proper web apps like this, and while I have all the PHP and JS knowledge I need to assemble the site, and I've worked with jQuery before, this one I am less sure about.

Am I better off storing users' weekly reports in one big table, or creating a separate database, in which each user has their own table, in turn containing that user's weekly reports? There's going to be far more pulling this data for charts done than there is altering or adding to it, so my goal is primarily efficiency and simplicity of storing/recalling the data.

The thing that has me most stumped is the best way to handle the fact that different users will have different amounts of products, and those amounts will change. In a user's first week, perhaps they log sales for 2 items, but come the third week, they add a new item to the list of things they are selling. The database needs to allow for this kind of thing with low overhead, as most users will have more than 1 product.

How would you structure this database?

Comment: One big table is much more scalable than one per user, but you'd be much better off with a normalized set of tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest one large table with the innoDB engine for row-level locking instead of table locking. Then create an index on the username and entry time.

I would suggest that the table per user be a bit much, you would be wasting space on the harddisk and database allocated for the table which a user may not need. There is no problem with mySQL support 5+ million rows, if your table even gets that big.

Simplicity is best.